# How to create a Activity Feed Rule for emails automatically being assigned to a case in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How do I create an activity feed rule that writes an **auto post** on the **Record Wall** of a case when an *email* is automatically assigned (made Regarding) to that case because of its tracking token?

Our users are having trouble realising that there is something new to look at in the case and this would go a long way to preventing them from missing an important event.

EDIT:

These solutions have already been considered

1. They don't want follow up tasks.
2. The email is already displayed in a grid on the case
3. They don't want more Queues to check.
4. They don't want more emails to deal with.

This user is recalcitrant to say the least...they only want a note to appear on the record wall of the case.

Comment: The Activity Feed and Record Wall are CRM 2013 features, please update your question title and tags to reflect this.

Comment: They are 2011 features too. My question was about 2011. I don't need an answer for 2013 because I'm not using 2013.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this with little/no coding, you could:

1) create a task or other activity that would show up on the activity feed.  This is easily accomplished via workflow.

2) display the email/other activities in a grid on the case.

3) also set up queues to handle this.

4) send an email to the owner of the case when an activity gets appended to it.

There are a lot of options to resolve the issue of notifying users that their case has additional info.

EDIT:
Your comments are accurate and well received.  Can't you do something as simple as create a workflow that will create a post when an email is created and/or when set regarding field changes.  Then you can check within the workflow that the set regarding is for a case or else cancel the workflow.  Within the post record, set the type to auto and the regarding to the same regarding as the email.  (I was unable to get the record wall part working in my local VM, so I assumed that any post record regarding the case should show up in the case, but I couldn't test that).

Comment: None of these answers write a post on the record wall of a case in CRM 2011. My question was pretty explicit.